# jQuery AJAX request always fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

When I do this AJAX call

```
var BASE_URL =  "http://127.0.0.1:8000/index.php";
$.get(BASE_URL + "?r=category")
            .done(function (data) {
                alert('success');
            })
            .fail(function (error) {
                alert('error');
            });
```

this is the server response (inspected with Fiddler)

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 06 Jan 2015 13:46:19 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) PHP/5.5.8
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.8
X-Pagination-Total-Count: 3
X-Pagination-Page-Count: 1
X-Pagination-Current-Page: 1
X-Pagination-Per-Page: 20
Link: <http://127.0.0.1:8000/index.php?r=category%2Findex&page=1>; rel=self
Content-Length: 163
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

[{"CaID":1,"Name":"Brot und Gebäck","ParentCaID":null},{"CaID":2,"Name":"Süßes und Salziges","ParentCaID":null},{"CaID":3,"Name":"Getränke","ParentCaID":null}]
```

but it always calls the fail function.

Comment: are you missing to pass page=1 from ajax.get?

Comment: try $.getJSON() because your content type is 'application/json'

Comment: What are errors in fail callback? Your alert isn't very informative

Comment: @pankajparkar I think the content type is not the problem, jQuery documentation says `Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html)` for arg dataType

Comment: @Freez Thanks for heads up, might be D4Muck is missing required params.

Comment: @pankajparkar it is the same error with $.getJson()

Comment: @charlietfl if i use ths code
`.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {`
the textStatus is "error"
and the errorThrown is empty

Comment: are you calling from same domain, port & protocol?

Comment: @charlietfl No I am not. I am calling from another port.

Comment: then you need to CORS enable, set up jsonp, or go through proxy. That's a cross domain request. Yes you can see data in body but browser won't give you access to it

Comment: @charlietfl I added the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` tag to the header and now it works

Answer (score 0):

```
var BASE_URL =  "http://127.0.0.1:8000/index.php";
$.get(BASE_URL + "?r=category")
        .done(function (data) {
            alert('success');
        })
        .fail(function (error) {
            console.log(error);//to show what error happended
            alert('error');
        });
```